# Git merge master into branch commit ordering

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a GIT master branch with the following commits

```
Master:-
      commit one
      commit two
```

Now I created a new branch sprint1 and added the following

```
Sprint1:
      commit one
      commit two
      commit sprint1 one
```

THe master and sprint1 diverged at this point

```
Master:
      commit one
      commit two
      commit three

Sprint1:
      commit one
      commit two
      commit sprint1 one
      commit sprint1 two
      commit sprint1 three
```

Now, when I merge master into sprint1 , I get the following,

```
Sprint1
      commit one
      commit two
      commit sprint1 one
      commit three
      commit sprint1 two
      commit sprint1 three
      commit merged commit
```

but when I merged master into sprint1 I expected this following : -

```
Sprint1
      commit one
      commit two
      commit sprint1 one
      commit sprint1 two
      commit sprint1 three
      commit three
      commit merged commit
```

How its the former and not the latter.

Comment: how are you viewing the commit order? github? terminal? some other git tool?

Comment: command line terminal..

Comment: git log --oneline..which one is the correct order, "commit three" was done prior to "sprint 1 two" and "sprint 2 three"

Comment: i was using `git log --oneline --graph` which separates the branch commits putting them in order

Comment: This command really helps..Its as expected..Let me recreate and see it..Thanks much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.

To get the commits in the order you're expecting, try using:

```
git log --oneline --topo-order
```

This avoids showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed.

For more details see: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_ordering

You could also use `--graph` for a nicer output with the branch displayed separately. This implies the `--topo-order` option by default.

A quick log version i sometimes prefer, via an alias, is:

```
git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph -n 10
```